# How to react to end of dragging in a custom component

Tags: codenameone

I noticed that it is not guaranteed that a components pointerReleased method is called after its pointerPressed method has been called.

With a Conponent derivate - one that handles pointer events - what would be the recommended way to get notified of a pointer released event under all circumstances?

Say my custom component is supposed to be green and gets red when tapped. How would I warrant that it becomes green again when the pointer is no longer pressed?

---

New example - Component derivate with isStickyDrag() returning true - pointer events are logged - when the component is pressed and then dragged vertically the surrounding Container instance scrolls - no pointerReleased then:

```
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
    hi.setScrollableY(true);
    Component component = new Component() {
        @Override
        protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(120, 120);
        }
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics aGraphics) {
            aGraphics.setColor(0x000000);
            aGraphics.drawRoundRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1, 20, 20);
        }
        @Override
        protected boolean isStickyDrag() {
            return true;
        }
        protected int getDragRegionStatus(int x, int y) {
            return Component.DRAG_REGION_IMMEDIATELY_DRAG_XY;
        };
        @Override
        public void pointerPressed(int x, int y) {
            super.pointerPressed(x, y);
            Log.p("pointerPressed(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
        }
        @Override
        public void pointerReleased(int x, int y) {
            super.pointerReleased(x, y);
            Log.p("pointerReleased(" + x + ", " + y + ")");
        }
    };
    hi.add(component);
    hi.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should override the isStickyDrag method as such:

```
protected boolean isStickyDrag() {
    return true;
}
```

It already defines it and in this case should always receive pointer released events.

Comment: But it doesn't - see the new example with a Component derivate and the description. You can get into states where pointerReleased is not called even if isStickyDrag returns true.

Comment: That might be a bug but I haven't looked into it

Comment: See [Component derivate with isStickyDrag true but no pointerReleased](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2849)